# Reputation decreasing automatically

Tags: support, reputation

My reputation was 310 some days ago. I did not down-vote anyone's answers recently and I'm quite sure that no one down-voted my answers or questions as there were no records about them in my user page. I don't think there was a serial up-voting problem also. But my reputation has decreased to 304 now. I don't know how this has happened.

However it is interesting to note that it has not decreased suddenly to 304 but gradually in steps of 2. The same thing is happening to my [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/25870/dineshkumar) Stack Exchange account also (reduced from 254 to 252). What is the cause for this strange happening?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some posts you suggested edits on and gained +2 rep on them were deleted. This results in those edit reps getting reverted upon deletion of the post.

These kinds of reps are hidden by default on your reputation page. To show them, check the `show removed posts` check box at the bottom of the page:

[image]

Once you do that, you'll see `removed` entries in the reputation list, like this:

[image]

Comment: Was the post deleted or my edits were rolled back?

Comment: The posts were deleted. Rolling back the edits will not affect the awarded rep.

Comment: Wouldn't it be convenient if those kind of reputation changes were also shown in the reputation graph?

Comment: Aren't they showed in the graph already? Select the "show removed posts" checkbox at the bottom if you haven't already.