# I lost 2 reputation but no message in reputation tab

Tags: discussion

[image: Imgur]

[image: Imgur]

Today morning my reputation was 2799. I got +1 for [one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/678166/how-to-install-latest-version-of-nitroshare-on-ubuntu) question,then my reputation goes to 2804.But after some time I lost 2 reputation,but no message in reputation tab.

I know -2 is when one of my answer get down-voted ,but which one?

[image: Imgur]

My reputation tab in profile:

[image: Imgur]

Comment: Go to your profile and check the reputation tab there.

Comment: I verified there no clue

Comment: It's probably a post that you had edited when you were at less than 2k rep and the post got deleted. To show those reputation changes; At the bottom of the page, in the reputation tab, there is a "show removed posts"; Check it. http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7396/reputation-decreasing-automatically/7397#7397

Comment: @Dan thats correct!....please write it as answer.

Comment: It's better to just flag this as a duplicate to the other question, as it's the same issue.

Comment: ok then I vote to close..@Dan