# Why did I lose 2 points?

Tags: support, reputation

I lost 2 points for this:

[Script to change volume](https://askubuntu.com/questions/998160/script-to-change-volume)

I could not find out why I lost 2 reputation points.

Comment: Check the following question as well, not exactly your case but it helps https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/7396/reputation-decreasing-automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question is "Why" but the answer posted is "How".

I don't know "Who" down-voted you which is the only definitive way of finding out "why" because we can ask him or her.

I suspect the reason is they felt you were looking for someone to debug your script for you and/or they had little appreciation of ruby. Personally I skip over questions where I know nothing about them.

As for your question itself you might want to consider something other than `pactl` because I've had problems with it setting the volume accurately myself. If you read this: [Terminal command to set audio volume?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/97936/terminal-command-to-set-audio-volume) there are other options available.

Consolation prize: I'm up-voting your question here in meta :)

Answer (score 5):

Your question was voted down. From ["What is reputation? How do I earn (and lose) it?"](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation):

> **You lose reputation when:**
>
> - your question is voted down: −2

---

Voting is when someone clicks the up or down arrow to the left of a question or answer. Those arrows look like this on the main site:

[image: Voting arrows]

When your question is voted down, that means someone clicked on the down arrow.

Comment: I read the link. I do not know what "voted down" means.?

Comment: @fixit7 You can vote questions and answers up or down, up voting adds rep and down voting takes it away. You lose 2 points if someone votes a post of yours down, you lose 2 rep, up you gain 5, 10 on answers.

Comment: @fixit7 I've added what voted down means.

Comment: @fixit7 FWIW, you can also [see your own reputation changes](https://askubuntu.com/users/573838/fixit7?tab=reputation), and you can see the -2 because you received a down-vote.

Comment: So, if someone didn't like my post for whatever reason, they downvote it? I personally would not down vote someone unless they were belligerent and/or showed absolutely no effort.

Comment: @fixit7 downvoting is not personal - we are not downvoting the user, but the post. Maybe someone thought your question is not useful to the site for some reason, or maybe [Tim Post just lost his keys](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215379/should-drive-by-downvoting-be-more-effectively-caught/215397#215397)

Comment: The user makes the post. So down voting post = down voting poster. I won't take it personal. Some people may be having a bad day. :-)

Comment: @fixit7 the difference is this - if someone is downvoting everyone one of your posts just because you posted it, that is indeed downvoting the user. But if someone downvoted just some particular post because of some perceived issue, that's downvoting just the post.